# What is this called in recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to figure out how to reverse a linked list and came across this weird concept where when you don't "return" a recursive function instead just calling the function, the function processes all of the data after the recursive call backwards. Does anyone know what this is called or how this works. Does it happen simultaneously... which i doubt or is it just a caveat of the recursive function to process data in reverse after the return statement at the top or right before the return statement at the top executes. Weird question so here is an example...

```js
function wow(cool) {
    if(cool === 10) return;
    cool += 1;
    console.log(cool);
    wow(cool);
    console.log(cool);
}

wow(0);
```

The question is simply when does the second console.log happen.

Comment: Does it happen simultaneously --> if we're ralking about browser-side javascript, there is no "at once" concept.

Comment: The example is too simple. Not sure what your question is about that. A function whose purpose is only to do some `console.log` calls, isn't all that useful. In general, you should prefer a recursive function to return the result. But please provide some specific code that is not meaningless.

Comment: Try using your developer tools and step through your code line by line. You will understand what happens in very short time by yourself. Promised!

Comment: seems like both `console.log` are executed at the same time. but the second is only show after the `wow` in `wow` is executed. Guess this only happens because `wow` inside `wow` is never returned.

Comment: The question is simply when does the second console.log happen.

Comment: There's nothing special about not returning the value of the function call. But since you are not interested in the returned value, one might argue you are only interested in its side effects. So basically, a recursive function with side effects... if I'd call it anything.

Answer (score 2):

In the example below, all the `before` calls are completed before the `after` calls, because the stack needs to finish traversing downward, before it travels back up the stack (in reverse).

```js
class Visitor { before(val){} after(val){} }

const looper = (visitor, start = 0, max = 10) => {
  if (start >= max) return;
  visitor.before(start);
  looper(visitor, start + 1, max);
  visitor.after(start);
}

class MyVisitor extends Visitor {
  before (val) { console.log(`BEFORE : ${val}`); }
  after  (val) { console.log(`AFTER  : ${val}`); }
}

looper(new MyVisitor(), 0, 10);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: ahhh. Thank you, this makes sense. Interesting concept.

Comment: While an interesting explanation, ISTM that it would be simpler and easier to understand without the `class` and `extends`, with only `const visitor = {before: /* ... */, after: /* ... */}; ... looper (visitor, 0, 10)`

Comment: @ScottSauyet I was simulating interfacing and typing similar to TS.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: Yes, understood.  I just didn't know *why*!  But maybe that's just the part of me that simply wants nothing to do with TS.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It may help to realise that each (recursive) execution of the function has its own `cool` variable. It is not a variable that is common to all these executions. Each time a new recursive call is made, a new version of this variable is created that gets its value from the argument that is passed on. When a bit later `+= 1` is executed on it, only *that* particular variable changes. All those previous variables with the same name, remain as they were.

In the example code, the top level call will create that variable with a value of 0 (since that is passed to it), which will increase to 1, and then never ever changes in its life time.

The first *recursive* call results in a new variable with the same name, that starts with value 1. It gets incremented to 2, and then never changes again.

Each of these versions of `cool` live in their own "box". You can visualise the execution as a set of nested boxes.

Let's limit the function to continue until 3 so we don't have that much to monitor:

```
function wow(cool) {
    if(cool === 3) return;
    cool += 1;
    console.log(cool);
    wow(cool);
    console.log(cool);
}

wow(0);
```

Then here are the execution contexts that are created... each box is such a context. Execution flows from top to bottom:

```js
+----------------------------------------------+
| cool = 0                                     |
| cool += 1 // = 1                             |
| console.log(cool) // 1                       |
|   +--------------------------------------+   |
|   | cool = 1                             |   |
|   | cool += 1 // = 2                     |   |
|   | console.log(cool) // 2               |   |
|   |   +------------------------------+   |   |
|   |   | cool = 2                     |   |   |
|   |   | cool += 1 // = 3             |   |   |
|   |   | console.log(cool) // 3       |   |   |
|   |   |   +-----------------------+  |   |   |
|   |   |   | cool = 3              |  |   |   |
|   |   |   | if (cool == 3) return |  |   |   |
|   |   |   +-----------------------+  |   |   |
|   |   | console.log(cool) // 3       |   |   |
|   |   +------------------------------+   |   |
|   | console.log(cool) // 2               |   |
|   +--------------------------------------+   |
| console.log(cool) // 1                       |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Note how each `cool` lives in its own box, and is not influenced by the variable(s) that live in the deeper nested boxes.